# How to capture client side javascript errors in geb?

Tags: javascript, testing, groovy, automated-tests, geb

Is there any way to capture javascript errors programmatically using geb? I looked at the geb API but I cannot find anything useful.

Comment: What browser are you using?  I think PhantomJS may dump JS errors to the console.

Comment: My idea is to have a browser agnostic solution. I have found a selenium extension for firefox (https://github.com/mguillem/JSErrorCollector). It would be nice to have some sort of listener not dependent from the browser I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't anything built-in in Geb for that.

Not knowing what your exact use case is I can only suggest to handcraft a solution where you would inject a js `window.onerror` handler either when rendering the page or from Geb after page load which collects all the errors and puts them somewhere in DOM to be then accessed by your Geb code. Some suggestions can probably be found in [this blog post on capturing JavaScript errors in WebDriver](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/capturing-javascript-errors-in.html).

There are also many js frameworks that allow to record js errors, you could use one of them.